# wordpress - call a function when a comment is posted

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I would like to take some action in php whenever someone posts a comment. How can I set up a hook for that? I assume it would go in functions.php...

EDIT - here is my udpated code:

```
add_action('comment_post', 'comment_posted');


    function comment_posted() {
        $MyClass = new MyClass(); //I do this in other functions and don't have any blank screen problems
            $test = "";
            $MyClass->doSomething($test); 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_new_comment

> Calls 'comment_post' action with comment ID and whether comment is approved by WordPress.

You should be able to then call `add_action('comment_post', 'my_func');` from within your functions.php.

Comment: Thank you. It works, and the function is called. However, the screen goes blank (white) when a comment is added. I'm not echoing anything to the screen. Do you know how I can just get the user back to the post they commented on instead of getting a blank screen?

Comment: Do you have some example code? It's hard to guess what's happening in your function. You could try setting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` temporarily to see if an error is being thrown somewhere.

Comment: Added some code above. Error reporting doesn't show any errors.

Comment: can you please tell us how you did to Call 'comment_post' action with comment ID and whether comment is approved by WordPress.