# How to perform custom action when WordPress comment is posted?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, setcookie

I am trying to set a custom cookie when a visitor submits a comment, but I can not seem to get this working. Here's what I have in functions.php:

```
add_action('comment_post', 'ipro_set_comment_cookie');

function ipro_set_comment_cookie($comment) {
    setcookie("visitor_name", $comment->comment_author, time()+86400);
    setcookie("visitor_email", $comment->comment_author_email, time()+86400);
}
```

I've also tried changing `comment_post` to `wp_insert_comment`- neither have seemed to work. I am working off of WP's action references: 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Comment.2C_Ping.2C_and_Trackback_Actions

...any ideas?

Comment: I believe you're looking for this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759882/wordpress-call-a-function-when-a-comment-is-posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Database writes in the [Filter Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference)

Try something like `comment_save_pre`

> applied to the comment data just prior to updating/editing comment data. Function arguments: comment data array, with indices "comment_post_ID", "comment_author", "comment_author_email", "comment_author_url", "comment_content", "comment_type", and "user_ID".

That way it sets on submit (so it calls after your error handling kicks in)

If I understand your question correctly, this should work:

```
add_action('comment_save_pre', 'ipro_set_comment_cookie');

function ipro_set_comment_cookie($comment) {
    setcookie("visitor_name", $comment->comment_author, time()+86400);
    setcookie("visitor_email", $comment->comment_author_email, time()+86400);
}
```